# Need design pattern suggestion: AsyncTask included

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-intentservice

This is my current situation.

```
Class Foo{
    public static boolean isAsyncTask1Done;
    public static boolean isAsyncTask2Done;
    AsyncTask1(); //in onPostExecute make isAsyncTask1Done= true
    AsyncTask2(); //in onPostExecute make isAsyncTask2Done= true
    //execute the following method after the above 2 complete.

    if (isAsyncTask1Done == true && isAsyncTask2Done == true)
        doPostProcessing();
}
```

Now this class is also an activity. Also since the AsyncTask1(); and AsyncTask2(); will take sometime, I have make them as Async tasks (I might make them as intentservice).

Now my question if how should I call doPostProcessing() ? I need to call this only when AsyncTask1() and AsyncTask2() are done.

Thanks

Comment: Do both `AcyncTasks` need to run at the same time?  Or can you just start the second one when the first one has completed?

Comment: I think you should use two Threads, run it and use join() to wait until them finish to work.

Comment: Just a fix - u need three threads. One MainThread that will run other two threads and join them. When they will finish, MainThread will call an callback.

Comment: @DanielNugent : Any order is fine. I wanted them to be both `AcyncTasks` so that they both can run in 2 diff. threads and process faster as suppose to do them sequentially. Also, like I said before they will the process hungry so I did not want them to put on UI as std. methods.

Comment: @AlexanderRavikovich I guess you are closer to the solution. Just wanted to make sure that when you say threads, these are the regular `java threads` and not `AcyncTasks` or 'IntentService`.

Comment: Yes, I talked about Java Threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have your example set up, it won't work.  The event needs to be triggered by the last `AsyncTask` completing.

Start the AsyncTasks:

```
new AsyncTask1.execute();
new AsyncTask2.execute();
```

Then, when the last one is complete, call `doPostProcessing()`.

Edit:  Added `synchronized` blocks.

```
    private boolean asyncTask1Completed = false;
    private boolean asyncTask2Completed = false;
    private boolean ranPostProcessing = false;

    private class AsyncTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //......
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String result = "result";
            //......
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            asyncTask1Completed = true;

            synchronized(MainActivity.this) {
                if (asyncTask2Completed && !ranPostProcessing) {
                    ranPostProcessing = true;
                    //Call doPostProcessing once both AsyncTasks are complete:
                    doPostProcessing();
                }
            }


        }
    }

    private class AsyncTask2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //......
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String result = "result";
            //......
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            asyncTask2Completed = true;

            synchronized(MainActivity.this) {
                if (asyncTask1Completed && !ranPostProcessing) {
                    ranPostProcessing = true;
                    //Call doPostProcessing once both AsyncTasks are complete:
                    doPostProcessing();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a chance that  doPostProcessing(); will run twice if two tasks will finish at the same time. The problem is concurrent access to variable ranPostProcessing from two tasks... This may work in 99% but in 1% this code may run doPostProcessing() twice and break all the system...

Comment: @AlexanderRavikovich That is true.  I suppose using a `synchronized` block to call `doPostProcessing()` would fix it.  Honestly, I think the suggestion you made in the comments would be the best route for this though.

Answer (score 0):

In PostExcecute of task1 you check if task2 has been done. If so, do postexecute. If not, do nothing. Same for task2 checking if task 1 has been done.

And you need to .execute() the tasks.

And I'm sure that if you have a close look at your app, there's better ways to do it than this.